# Vino claims it's running when it's not

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, vino

I'm trying to start vino on an Ubuntu 14.04 box from the command line, but vino claims it's already running:

```
$ ps auxww | grep vino
myusername 17566  0.0  0.0  15940   920 pts/42   S+   19:04   0:00 grep --color=auto vino

$ /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0

(vino-server:17570): EggSMClient-CRITICAL **: egg_sm_client_set_mode: assertion 'global_client == NULL || global_client_mode == EGG_SM_CLIENT_MODE_DISABLED' failed
** Message: The desktop sharing service is already running, exiting.
```

I tried following the advice at ([can't start vino VNC service on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199075/cant-start-vino-vnc-service-on-ubuntu-12-04)) but it didn't help.

Why does vino claim it's already running when it's not? How can I start it?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to restart vino-server because I could not connect anymore. I tried the way you did but it did not work out. What help for me:

```
sudo pkill Xorg
```

Afterwards

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

says:

```
Server is already active for display 0
```

So I deleted:

```
sudo rm  /tmp/.X0-lock
```

And restarted vino afterwards:

```
nohup /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0
```

Note: It still told me already running but now I could connect to it via VNC anyways.

Comment: Did not work for me. After `nohup...` I also still get `** Message: The desktop...`, but in addition `$ pgrep vino` returns nothing.